# How do I make a TImage move (like a DVD logo)

Tags: c++builder-6, timage

I am trying to make a TImage move like a DVD logo, but the TImage is not moving.

This is the code I used:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DVDLogoTimer(TObject *Sender)
{
    image->Left+=xPos; image->Top+=yPos;

    if (image->Left <= invisibleHelperObject->Left) xPos=-xPos;
    if (image->Top <= invisibleHelperObject->Top) yPos=-yPos;
    if (image->Left+image->Width >= invisibleHelperObject->Width) xPos=-xPos;
    if (image->Top+image->Height >= invisibleHelperObject->Height) yPos=-yPos;

    Label1->Caption = IntToStr(xPos) + " | " + IntToStr(yPos);
}
```

(X and Y variables are not even changing (stays at 0))

Comment: Maybe the function isn't called?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I just figured it out, I wasn't setting the X and Y variables initially to a value other then 0 (when I set it to 3 it worked).

Answer (score 0):

In C++Builder 6 (and the "classic" Borland compiler in modern versions), you can't use *compound operators* like `+=` with properties.  Doing so will *read* the property value into a temporary and then modify the temporary, but will not *assign* the temporary back to the property. Using compound operators on properties requires a modern Clang-based compiler:

[Differences Between Clang-enhanced C++ Compilers and Previous Generation C++ Compilers, __property: Compound and Chained Assignment](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Differences_Between_Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers_and_Previous-Generation_C%2B%2B_Compilers#property:_Compound_and_Chained_Assignment)

> Clang-enhanced C++ compilers support compound assignment of `__property`, **while BCC32 does not**.
>
> The objects of the keyword `__property` are not like fields or members. They should be used in **simple assignments**.
>
> Although both BCC32 and the RAD Studio Clang-enhanced C++ compilers allow `__property` to be used in compound assignments such as:
>
> `Form1->Caption += DateToStr(Now());`
>
> **BCC32 only invokes the getter, not the setter.** Therefore we recommend that you avoid such constructs when targeting multiple platforms.
>
> None of these compilers support the usage of `__property` in chained assignment, as in:
>
> `Button2->Caption = Button1->Caption = DateToStr(Now()); // Error`

So, in your situation, when you invoke `image->Left += xPos;` for instance, it acts *as-if* you had written this instead:

```
//image->Left += xPos;
int temp = image->Left;
temp += xPos;
```

So, you need to use the `+` and `=` operators separately instead, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DVDLogoTimer(TObject *Sender)
{
    image->Left = image->Left + xPos;
    image->Top = image->Top + yPos;
    ...
}
```